# Access Redux store outside React when using next-redux-wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I have a NextJS React app that uses the next-react-wrapper (basically a HOC) on `_app.tsx` like so:

**_app.tsx**

```
...
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';

class Page extends App<Props> {
  ...
}

export default withRedux(reduxStore)(Page);
```

**store.ts**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';

import rootReducer from './reducer';

export default (
  initialState: any = undefined,
) => createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware()),
);
```

I'm struggling to work out how to access the store outside of React such as in a simple helper function. My `store.ts` file exports a `makeStore` function which is needed (including the initial state) for the next-redux-wrapper HOC.

I could access the store in a React component and pass it to my helper functions as an argument each time but that seems messy.

Is there a way to access the store direct from non React helper function modules?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but found the solution.

The Readme of this lib gives the example of `makeStore` function like this:

```
const makeStore = (initialState, options) => {
    return createStore(reducer, initialState);
};
```

You need to modify it a bit

```
let store;
const makeStore = (initialState, options) => {
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
return store;
};

export {store}
```

Now you can import the store from wherever  you want.

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me with TS

```
let store: ReturnType<typeof configStore>

const configStore = () => configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(thunkMiddleware),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});

export const makeStore = () => {
  store = configStore();
  return store;
};

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, AppState, unknown, Action>;
export type AppDispatch = ReturnType<AppStore['dispatch']>;

export const wrapper = createWrapper<AppStore>(makeStore, { debug: false });

export { store };
```

Answer (score 4):

It may not be preferable, but the store can be accessed from the window using a `storeKey`. The default key is `__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__` and using it look like this:

```
window.__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__.getState()
```

[Here's where that happens](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/blob/master/packages/wrapper/src/index.tsx#L34-L36)

The key (`storeKey`) can be changed in the second options parameter passed to the withRedux function parameter. For your implementation it looks like this:

```
export default (
  initialState: any = undefined,
  { storeKey: 'whateveryouwant' } // the name on the exposed store variable
) => createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware()),
);
```

Comment: Is there any way to access it from server side because window becomes undefined

Comment: For a statically compiled app (using `next export`), would the store's state be reset on every refresh? If so... how does one fix that issue?

Comment: @7ball yes and that will be the case for a SSR and SSG (static) site. The most popular solution to this is using a state-persistence library (e.g. redux-persist).

Answer (score -1):

You can create high-order function to wrap any other function with store. Here is simple example that pass store as `this` argument to any other function.

```
function withReduxFunction(store) {
    return function (connectedFunction) {
        return function (...args) {
            connectedFunction.call(store, ...args);
        }
    }
}
```

And usage. For example we want to provide store to this function

```
function doSomthingWothStore(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(this);   // This will be store
    console.log("arg1: " + arg1 + " arg2 " + arg2);
}
```

Do

```
const funcWithStore = withReduxFunction(store)(doSomthingWothStore);
```

Now you can call `funcWithStore` and `this` will be equal to store.

You can play with high-order function to make it suitable for you (i.e. pass store as first argument and so on).

Also you can take a look at `useDispatch` and `useSelector` [hooks from react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks). They also should work with any function.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as accessing store from the React component and passing it as an argument to my function manually?

Comment: This is somewhat similar to how component is conected to store with `withRedux`. You connect once, and then call it many times without explicitly passing the store

Answer (score -3):

You can import store module wherever it is needed and directly access the store functions like `store.getState()`. However, you need to subscribe to store to be notified of any change in the state.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would import store to a function in my scenario. The store is created inside a function and via next-with-redux HOC. I don't see an easy way to import the store...

Comment: You have to export the store from the module where it is instantiated and import that module everywhere.

Comment: How can I export it when it doesn't get initialised until its wrapping function is called? This is how next-with-redux HOC works.

Answer (score -3):

You can create store first and then return it from makeStore()

```
export const store = createStore(...)
const makeStore() {
  return store
}
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: true })
```