# access store of next-redux-wrapper from non component

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I have a next app with next-redux-wrapper and my store code

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducers";
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

export default (initialState = undefined, { storeKey = "app" }) => {
  return createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));
};
```

I am importing the store and export app withRedux next-redux-wrapper

All things works fine but I want to access the store from non component files

```
import store from "../redux/store";
export const lang = store(undefined, { storeKey: "app" }).getState().user
  .language;
```

lang not changed when I change it in main store

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Redux store outside React when using next-redux-wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805679/access-redux-store-outside-react-when-using-next-redux-wrapper)